# Ember.js: Wrapping Ember.Checkbox with another element that uses its ID

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use a third-party checkbox with Ember and am having trouble getting it to work.  The third-party checkbox needs markup like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" name="bar" class="baz"/>
<label for="foo">blah</label>
```

I thought the easiest thing would be to create my own view FancyCheckbox that would encapsulate this pattern.  The main obstacle seems to be using the checkbox's ID in the label's `for` attribute.  Here's what I tried:

```
App.FancyCheckbox = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  templateName: 'fancyCheckbox',
  tagName: '',
});
```

And here's the template I used:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="fancyCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" {{bindAttr id="view.elementId"}}/>
  <label {{bindAttr for="view.elementId"}}/>
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't get the checkbox's events properly.  I assume this is related to the lack of an enclosing div.  But when I make an enclosing div, I can't figure out how to wire up attribute bindings to the checkbox properly.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYHNJ/) demonstrating what I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `tagName: ''` was screwing your FancyCheckbox up http://jsfiddle.net/mlienau/pEfwt/

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I knew that `tagName: ''` was screwing things up, but I didn't realize that Ember would append the template to the input tag and then surround the whole thing with a div.